# Pass parameter to access modifier

Tags: solidity, blockchain, modifiers

how can I pass a parameter to an access modifier both in Solidity and Web3.
Let's assume I have the following code:

```
modifier passwordRequired(string _pw){
  require(keccak256(_pw) == keccak256("topSecret"));
  _;
}

function doSomething(unit _param) public passwortRequired(_pw){
  ...
}
```

How can I call function `doSomething` and pass a string to the access modifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass parameter in solidity function then same parameter is passed to modifier. you don't need to pass separate parameter for **modifier.**

Lets change your code as:

```
 modifier passwordRequired(string _pw){
  require(keccak256(_pw) == keccak256("topSecret"));
  _;
}

function doSomething(string _param) public passwordRequired(_param){
  //...
}
```

This code says that the parameter `_param` you sent is the `password` . If you want to pass separate password other then `_param` then you have to pass other parameter in function.

> function doSomething(string _param, string _pw) public
>   passwordRequired(_pw){...}

Now you see that same function parameter `_pw` is passed to modifier `passwordRequired(_pw)`.

Answer (score 3):

Add modifier parameter to function parameter as well:

```
modifier passwordRequired(string _pw){
  require(keccak256(_pw) == keccak256("topSecret"));
  _;
}

function doSomething(unit _param, string _pw) public passwortRequired(_pw){
  ...
}
```